# Is it possible to use the L8 OLI/TIRS COLLECTIONS LAND SURFACE REFLECTANCE Landsat8 product for calculation of the surface temperature?

Tags: surface

Is it possible to use the L8 OLI/TIRS COLLECTIONS LAND SURFACE REFLECTANCE Landsat8 product for calculation of the temperature of the Earth surface?

I examined the following sources about this product:

Landsat 8 OLI/TIRS Level-2 Data Products - Surface Reflectance
https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/L8Level2SR

Landsat Surface Reflectance Level-2 Science Products
https://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat-surface-reflectance-data-products

PRODUCT GUIDE LANDSAT SURFACE REFLECTANCE-DERIVED SPECTRAL INDICES 
https://landsat.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/documents/si_product_guide.pdf

But I didn’t find information about the Surface Temperature Data.
Also I download an example of this product and can’t find the surface temperature there.

However, one of the main purposes of TIRS bands of Landsat-8 – is getting the surface temperature. Also, it’s rather difficult to calculate the surface temperature on its own, since many procedures have to be done by users (corrections, calculations).

Thus, I suppose that L8 OLI/TIRS COLLECTIONS LAND SURFACE REFLECTANCE product should have the surface temperature and I just can’t find it.

May somebody help me to understand this subject.

Comment: You've got too much UPPER CASE to make this question legible. Questions which generate squinting and pain don't get as much dwell time as those that are relatively pain-free.